# Is it recommended to upgrade to Lubuntu 15.04?

Tags: upgrade

Currently I have installed Lubuntu 14.10 on my EEE PC 701, but I am thinking of upgrading to Lubuntu 15.04. Do you recommend to upgrade to Lubuntu 15.04 and why?

Comment: i would recomment you to  go for 14.04 LTS. 14.10 and 15.04 are not LTS( Long Term Support ) but 14.04 is.  That means 14.04 LTS has a support life span of 5 years. check:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lubuntu 14.10 is not an LTS release. It is supported 9 months. So less than in 3 months the support will be dropped. So it is recomended to upgrade. If you do not want to upgrade frequently consider installng an LTS release. It is supported for 3 years. Current LTS release is 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Your 14.10 release will go end-of-life (no more support) in July - I would recommend upgrading to 15.04 before that date.  15.04 is also not a long term release, and will go end-of life in January 2016.

I would also recommend making a backup of your data before trying to do an upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Support for 14.10 will end July 2015.

I would advice to plan your upgrade before supports end. When it does all the repositories get moved to an archive making it more difficult to keep your system updated and the security updates stop at that time too.